# ZFS NFS Shares not exported Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, nfs, zfs

I am setting up ZFS and NFS on Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS and have a weird issue that is causing me to go crazy. I have set up ZFS and NFS using ZFS shares as described in https://pthree.org/2012/12/31/zfs-administration-part-xv-iscsi-nfs-and-samba/. As you can see in my log below, although I have set zfs-share to run `zfs share -a` during boot, the shares are still not exported. Even weirder, is that  `zfs share -a` still doesn't when I manually run it. I can only get zfs shares to work if I reset the `sharenfs` property of one of the shares and then re-run `zfs share -a`. See below

```
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/mnt localhost
$ sudo zfs share -a
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/mnt localhost
$ sudo zfs share pool1
cannot share 'pool1': filesystem already shared
$ sudo zfs get sharenfs pool1
NAME   PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
pool1  sharenfs  on        local
$ sudo zfs set sharenfs=on pool1
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/s/apu/a/homes *
/s/apu/a       *
/s/apu/a/sys   *
/mnt           localhost
$ sudo zfs share -a
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/s/apu/b       *
/s/apu/a/homes *
/s/apu/a       *
/s/apu/a/sys   *
/s/apu/b/cwc   *
/mnt           localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this looks like there's at least one bug in the interaction between the NFS server and the `sharenfs` setting:

- First, if any filesystem has `sharenfs` enabled, the calls to `zfs share -a` should be making those filesystems visible over NFS (as you expected). I'm fairly certain this is a bug.
- Second, it's surprising that the second `zfs share -a` call exposed any extra filesystems (`/s/apu/b` and `/s/apu/b/cwc`). This isn't necessarily a separate bug (perhaps the `zfs set sharenfs=on` call fixed something internal that was causing `zfs share -a` to fail before, so it's actually the same issue as above), however if `/s/apu/b` is on `pool1` then I would also be surprised by this behavior.

The OpenZFS community (and the Linux sub-community in particular) is very friendly and active -- I'd recommend filing an issue against their Github page to get more eyes on the problem: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues